# Spring Data Neo4j - Two graphs

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

I have to write a small application which collects data from one graph, and after some logic-magic, persists into a different graph.

I already have repositories using Spring Data Neo4j for both graphs.

Is there a way to connect to two Neo4j servers from the same application, and use one of them from a subset of repositories, and the second one from the others?

Comment: why not? you can have two different instances of Neo4j server object

Comment: It is more of a question of how... As my repositories are autogenerated by SDN, they are using a Neo4jServer bean. And, as far as I know, though I can have two beans of this type, I can't tell the repository which one to use. Or can I?